# SQL Script to findout Numeric Value

Tags: sql

I need to filter it out the number from my table. for example,

```
Id      url 
001     /testing
002     /testing2
003     /24678
```

From the above table, i need to fetch the numeric value ( 24678 - which is dynamically creating) and should update with some string like "my-testing". how to write SQL script for this?

thanks in advance.

- Liyakath

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MS SQL Server 2008, Oracle, MySQL etc

Answer (score 0):

According to your data this will work for **t sql** but URL will have more than one occurrences of **'/'**  and also so many other factors which I will try to address later but quickly:

```
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(100)

SET @url = '/testing'
SELECT isnumeric(SUBSTRING(@URL, PATINDEX ( '/%', @URL) + 1, len(@url)))

SET @url = '/testing2'
SELECT isnumeric(SUBSTRING(@URL, PATINDEX ( '/%', @URL) + 1, len(@url)))


SET @url = '/1234'
SELECT isnumeric(SUBSTRING(@URL, PATINDEX ( '/%', @URL) + 1, len(@url)))
```